# Pattern to extend classes without modifying them (or knowing implementation details) (c#)

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, inheritance

I am modifying some code that sits between two established layers, and am having trouble figuring out what the best design is.

Currently the code calls a file access library, and returns an object to the caller.  I need to extend the returned object to add some custom dispose functionality.  I don't have access to the definitions of the passed objects (some are filestreams, for example)

It would save me a lot of work if I could create a child instance that behaves like a base instance, and can be created from a base instance, but that has some hidden extra functionality.  Can this be done without knowing the implementation details of the base class?

In code form that looks a lot like this:

```
private class FileObjectWithDispose : FileObject, IDisposable
{//voidaction is a delegate, this is .net 2.0
    private VoidAction _disposeCallback;

public static FileObjectWithDispose wrapFile(FileObject unWrappedFile, VoidAction DisposeAction)
{//Implementation missing, this is the crux of what I don't know how to do
    FileObjectWithDispose wrappedFile = new FileObjectWithDispose(unWrappedFile);
    wrappedFile._disposeCallback = DisposeAction;
    return wrappedFile;
}

private FileObjectWithDispose()
    : base(null, null)//base class does not have a default constructor
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("FileObjectWithDispose is a wrapper class which is intended only to be cast from a filestream.");
}

private void Dispose()
{
    _disposeCallback();
    base.Dispose();
}
```

}

a sample call would look like this:

```
Connect(file, username, password, domain);
return FileObjectWithDispose.wrapFile(OpenFile(path), () => { Disconnect(file, username); });
```

The key difficulty I'm having is, if it's possible, how do I take a base class instance and create a decorated instance if the base class does not implement an interface that allows itself to be decorated?
Any ideas how to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Comment: you are describing decorator pattern if i am not mistaken. look into it.

Comment: you are doing it right, go ahead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The decorator pattern is the way to go.

1. Create an interface `ICustomDisposeAction` (an example name)
2. Implement this interface with all those possible classes which on you would want to perform `DisposeAction` on.

   FileObjectWithDispose : FileObject, IDisposable, ICustomDisposeAction
3. Create another class Decorator which also implements `ICustomDisposeAction`. Pass the original base class through the constructor of the decorator and then call the decorator's `DisposeAction` on it.

> ```
> public class Decorator : ICustomDisposeAction
> {
>   public FileObject wrappedFile { get; set; } 
>   public Decorator(FileObject unWrappedFile,...)
>   {
>     wrappedFile = unWrappedFile;
>     //Do your custom dispose here
>   }
> }
> ```

1. In those situations which demands a custom way of disposing the object, create the decorator object and do the custom dispose!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks like maybe there is a typo in the decorator class though?  As implemented, wrappedFile in the decorator is an instance of the base class, so it does not have the disposeCallback member to assign to.  Second, I don't think constructors can return values.

Comment: @AlexWeitzer, oopsie. I have removed the offending code. You can create a decorator class that has a disposeCallback member. You probably have to do that outside the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Try use Decorator pattern. [This](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) link can help.

Comment: Thanks.  The decorator pattern as I previously understood it requires the base class to implement an interface that allows itself to be decorated.  I assume there must be a way around that like TheSilverBullet is hinting at, but so far I do not see how to make it work given that I don't want to modify the base object, and I am not creating instances of the base object within my code.  The crux of the matter is, if it's possible, how do I take a base class instance and create a decorated instance?

Comment: @AlexWeitzer, you would need to have a common interface for the decorator pattern. So, the base class needs to be modified to allow this! Or, you can create class which has a member of (generalized) type of the base class. Then you can have the custom dispose code to work on this.