# Add behaviour to overridden overloads that call each other

Tags: c#, overriding, overloading

Let's say I'm using a library with a non-sealed class. I know the class's interface, but not its implementation. It is a bit like this:

```
public class LibraryClass
{
    public virtual void DoStuff()
    {
        //Unknown implementation
    }

    public virtual void DoStuff(int value)
    {
        //Unknown implementation
    }
}
```

I want to use this class but add my own behaviour to each call of either `DoStuff` overload. An apparently naive way to go about it would be:

```
public class MyClass : LibraryClass
{
    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
        base.DoStuff();
    }

    public override void DoStuff(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called");
        base.DoStuff(value);
    }
}
```

At first glance it looks OK, but if I call `DoStuff()` from my class I see the output "Called" twice. It seems that the actual implementation of `LibraryClass.DoStuff()` (which I can only guess at) must be similar to this:

```
public virtual void DoStuff()
{
    DoStuff(0);
}
```

And since `DoStuff(int)` is overridden, this ends up calling my own implementation, hence the added behaviour is called twice in the end.

One way to fix this would be to only override `DoStuff(int)`, since it will be called either way, but there's no way to be sure that some future version of this library won't change `DoStuff()` to *not* call `DoStuff(int)`.

I could also do something complex, like this:

```
public class MyClass : LibraryClass
{
    private bool isInCall = false;

    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        if (!isInCall)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called");
        }

        isInCall = true;

        base.DoStuff();

        isInCall = false;
    }

    public override void DoStuff(int value)
    {
        if (!isInCall)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called");
        }

        isInCall = true;

        base.DoStuff(value);

        isInCall = false;
    }
}
```

but it seems kind of sloppy.

Is there a more elegant way to override all overloads, but ensure that my added code is only executed once?

Comment: You could check the call stack in `DoStuff(int)` to see if it's coming from `DoStuff`, but a better solution would be to understand _why_ `DoStuff(int)` is being called from the base  method. Typically you see this when an overloaded method is created to supply a "default" parameter value, in which case you probably only want to override the "full" method.

Comment: I would recommend evaluating the Decorator design pattern. See a similar (sort of) question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274960/pattern-to-extend-classes-without-modifying-them-or-knowing-implementation-deta

Comment: If your assumption of `DoStuff(0);` is correct then the result is correct you will see **Called** twice.